# xml.setRequestHeader fails with SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying the following code:

```
    // create a request
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml.open("GET", url, false);
    xml.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Negotiate " + base64Token);
```

and it fails at the last line (setRequestHeader) with the error:

> SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12

I've tried debugging it but not entirely sure why this is happening! I am opening the request before setting the header and I haven't sent it yet.

I am currently testing this on Chrome 21

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Not sure, but just try this, change you variable name from `xml` to somethingelse.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately, that did not work. (Changed the name from xml to request)

Comment: can you go for `Jquery`?

Comment: I am willing to try if that solves the problem, what do you suggest (and thanks again for the help).

Comment: since such exceptions occur usually when a browser does not support some operation you are trying to do, And JQuery gives you a cross-browser support, so instead of creating XMLHTTPRequest, you create Jquery XMLHTTPRequest, that automatically instantiates the underlying browser XMLHTTP Object (XMLHHTPRequest  object varies with browser implementations & support), so you never get  such exceptions. you can explore `http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/` a bit here for using Jquery request mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the content of the base64Token variable? Looking at this error code, you're giving a wrong string value somewhere:

```
DOMException.SYNTAX_ERR 12 An invalid string value is specified.
```

Try setting another header, or the same but hardcoding the base64Token variable instead of concatenating it as a variable.
I'm less sure about this, but check also the URL and try with a know url like www.google.com just to see if it can be an issue.
Also if you're testing locally using a file:// protocol, that could be a source of issues dealing with XMLHttpRequest.

Also, as said Furqan, you may try to use a warper library, but I guess using jQuery just for this might be adding lot of code for just a little call.

Hope this helps!